# No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/3.7/

Tags: macos, python-3.7, setup.py

$ python3 setup.py install 
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-3544.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/
```

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).

When I use command which python3, I got the Path: /usr/local/bin/python3
What should I do?